# Function Pointers not working in getopt

Tags: c, function-pointers, getopt

I have some code which tests the robustness of a variety of PRNGs, and I want to choose which PRNG is being tested using options.

I have a function pointer type: `typedef double (*voidPRNG_ptr)(void);`

I have a testing function: `test_results* investigator_alloc(int N, voidPRNG_ptr RNGp)`
Where `test_results` is a typedef'ed struct.

I have PRNG functions: `double box_muller(void)`, `double rejection(void)`, `double RNG(void)`,  etc...

The following code in main works FINE:

```
int main(int argc, char** argv){ 
    int N = atoi(argv[1]);
    voidPRNG_ptr PRNGp = &box_muller; 

    test_results* results = investigator_alloc(N, PRNGp); 

    return 0;
    }
```

The box_muller function is used as the RNG, and data is as expected.

This also WORKS FINE:

```
int main(int argc, char** argv){ 
    int N = atoi(argv[1]);
    voidPRNG_ptr PRNGp = &box_muller; 

    PRNGp = &rejection; 

    test_results* results = investigator_alloc(N, PRNGp); 

    return 0;
    }
```

The rejection method is used as the RNG, as expected.

However, this DOESN'T work:

```
int main(int argc, char **argv){
   int opt;
   int atest = 0;
   voidPRNG_ptr PRNGp = &RNG;   //set default

   while((opt = getopt(argc, argv, "abur")) != -1){ 
        if(opt == 'a') {
            PRNGp = &normal_approx; 
            atest = 1;
        }           
        else if(opt == 'b') PRNGp = &box_muller; 
        else if(opt == 'u') PRNGp = &RNG; 
        else if(opt == 'r') PRNGp = &rejection; 
   }

    printf("\n %d\n",atest); 


    int N = atoi(argv[1]);
    //PRNGp = &rejection;
    //PRNGp = &normal_approx;
    //PRNGp = &box_muller; 

    test_results *results = investigator_alloc(N,PRNGp);
    return 0; 
}
```

I know that `getopt` is working as `atest` is set to the right value depending on the option selected. But there must be something wrong with the function pointer as the data is blank.

Any ideas? 
Thanks!

Comment: Completely unrelated, but if you call this program with `-a -b`, you first get `a`, settung `atest = 1`, and then you get `b`, leaving you with `box_muller` as `PRNGp`, but `atest` nevertheless set to `1`. Is that what you need?

Comment: And besides, even if your question is answered: your description "doesn't work" is a bit lousy, to be honest.

Comment: `atest` was just there to check weather the flags were being set at all. It wasn't really meant to be part of any working code. 

Fair enough, I should have detailed how it didn't work.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The issue is that you're applying `atoi()` to the first command-line argument, which is the option that tells your program which RNG to use. Since `argv[1]` is not numeric, you end up with `N=0` and no data.

Change `argv[1]` to `argv[optind]` (see [Using the `getopt` function](http://www.gnu.org/software/libc/manual/html_node/Using-Getopt.html#Using-Getopt)).

Comment: Wow I feel dumb, I should have picked that up. Thanks